# How to convert float to uint by float representation?

Tags: c#, floating-point, integer, data-conversion

In C I will do this to convert float representation of number into DWORD. Take the value from the address and cast the content to DWORD.

```
dwordVal = *(DWORD*)&floatVal;
```

So for example `44.54321` will become `0x42322C3F`.

How can I do the same in `C#`?

Comment: Actually `*(DWORD*)&floatVal` is the wrong way to do it in C as it breaks strict aliasing rules that C compilers rely on for optimisation. Correct ways involve a union (see C99tc3 footnote 82) or `memcpy()`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.touint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class:

```
uint value = BitConverter.ToUInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(44.54321F), 0);
Console.WriteLine("{0:x}", value); // 42322c3f
```

You could also do this more directly using an [`unsafe` context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx):

```
float floatVal = 44.54321F;
uint value;
unsafe { 
    value = *((uint*)(&floatVal));
}
Console.WriteLine("{0:x}", value); // 42322c3f
```

However, I'd strongly recommend avoiding this. See [Should you use pointers (unsafe code) in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584134/should-you-use-pointers-unsafe-code-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

Use the BitConverter class:

```
float f = 44.54321f;
uint u = BitConverter.ToUInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(f), 0);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(u == 0x42322C3F);
```

Answer (score 1):

In .NET Core 2.0 you can use [`BitConverter.SingleToInt32Bits()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.singletoint32bits?view=netcore-2.0). The reverse operation is [`BitConverter.Int32BitsToSingle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.int32bitstosingle?view=netcore-2.0)

.NET 6 added 2 more utilities:

- [`BitConverter.UInt32BitsToSingle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.uint32bitstosingle?view=net-6.0)
- [`BitConverter.SingleToUInt32Bits()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.singletouint32bits?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 0):

bitconvert creates a new byte array on every call.
this is the solution:

```
    unsafe public static float ToDecibel(this float x)
    {
        uint* y = (uint*)&x;
        (*y) &= 0x7fffffff;
        return (*y) * 7.17711438e-7f - 764.6161886f;
    }
```

Comment: +1 for remembering `unsafe`.  BUT ... This changes `x`! Better to use `uint y = *(uint*)&x; y &= 0x7fffffff; return y * 7.17711438e-7f - 764.6161886f;` to avoid changing `x`.