# Convert float to raw bits to int in C#

Tags: c#

We have something like:

```
float f = 1234.5678F;
```

Let's pretend the binary representation of this is `0x1234ABCD`. How can I get the value `305441741` (`==0x1234ABCD`) from `f`?

Comment: technically it already is in "raw bits", and it looks like you're trying to convert those raw bits to a string

Comment: I literally found a duplicate by using the first link in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+representation+float and I have never written a C# program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BitConverter class should help you.

[BitConverter.GetBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5be4sc9(v=vs.110).aspx)

Something like this:

```
float f = 1234.5678F;
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(f);
var result = string.Format("0x{0:x}{1:x}{2:x}{3:x}", bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]);
```